# Where does the 'up' in 'coffee up' come from?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I want to know what phrasal verb(s) 'coffee up' (as in 'it's good to coffee up for the day') is modelled on.

What does 'up' mean in such examples?

Comment: Any of a number: fill up (fuel tank, drinking glass), charge up (battery), etc.

Comment: the 'up' in your examples indicates completeness. But in 'coffee up', there is no completeness implied. It seems to suggest readiness. If someone coffees up for the day, he drinks coffee to make himself energetic for the day and get ready for a day's work.

Comment: Another term that was in vogue in the United States a few years ago was "Cowboy up"—that is, "Get up and get back after it." Hence, the longer form of the phrase, "Cowboy up, or go wait in the truck," a phrase with real resonance for anyone who spent time on a farm as a child, and was sometimes told to "go wait in the truck" when it became clear that the job would be easier to perform without the kid getting in the way. In the case of "coffee up," however, I think that the phrase amounts to the same thing as the verb "caffeinate."

Comment: The _up_ means 'to criterion, to completion; in the case of _coffee up, beer up,_ and in general _`consumed substance` up_ in active verb contexts, it means to consume as much as necessary at the moment, which may or may not be all that is eventually needed. Sort of like filling up the tank to an appropriate amount while on the road. This is not the same _up_ as _man up_ or _sit up_, but it is a phrasal verb.

Comment: I think an earlier example of the 'cowboy up' phrase that also connotes 'readiness' would be 'saddle up', which has the added bonus of being a physical action, supplying the 'up' (one wouldn't saddle down, would one?). I suspect most similar like phrases to be subsequent permutations, as I can't think of one that would pre-date saddles. ;)

Comment: Probably derived from "gas up", which likely is derived from the act of raising the level of the gasoline in the gas tank.

Comment: I wonder whether it is more to do with the class system, where in many (at least British) households, the cooking and preparation of hot drinks was carried our below stairs.  This was true not just of the aristocracy and plutocracy, but well down the social scale.  The cities and towns in Britain include hosts of homes with basements where cook or maid of all work would operate and bring tea 'up' to the family above.

Answer (score 1):

As Robusto suggests in a comment above, "coffee up" is modeled on such phrases as "charge up," "fuel up," "fill up," "load up," "build up," and "bulk up."

All of these phrases suggest maximizing one's reserves of whatever the commodity is in order to have as much of the commodity as possible available for the duration of the activity that follows the charging/fueling/filling/loading/building bulking up.

English also has the colloquial or idiomatic expressions "eat up" and "drink up," which similarly suggest drinking or eating to your limit or capacity.

As I noted in a comment above from January 2015, the ultimate sense of the exhortation to "coffee up" appears to be to encourage the listener to ingest lots of caffeine—which, since it is a stimulant, will tend to get the person "up."

Comment: I don’t think _eat up_ and _drink up_ are related here. Those two don’t suggest eating or drinking to **your** capacity, but finishing the portion that is given to you without leaving anything—whether that’s beyond your capacity or not. Another related phrase to _coffee up_ (the one I immediately thought of) is _stock up_. Coffeeing up is kind of like filling up your inner-body stock of coffee.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/up) sense 5 "Into the desired or a proper condition."